# Only secure content is displayed message in IE browser of newform.aspx of my SPList in SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, splist, internet-explorer, newform

I have created a new `SPList` and when I create on `newitem`, it opens the `newform.aspx`  as usual and strangely, am getting a message/warning message below of `IE browser`.

Am not facing this issue in `Google Chrome` and I have never faced this issue when I have developed many UIs along with SPServices, JSOM etc before.

Am having some amount of REST API code along with JavaScript written in the Content Editor of this NewForm.aspx page.
am stuck, at how to remove this warning message for IE browser? my customer prefers using IE than Chrome.

[image: only-secure-content]

Answer (score 1):

try add this site to Trusted (or Intranet) Zone in Internet Explorer, it should resolve this:

1. In Internet Explorer, click **Tools**, click **Internet Options**, and then
   click the **Security tab**.
2. In the Select a Web content zone to specify its current security
   settings box, click **Trusted Sites**, and then click **Sites**.
3. If you want to add sites that do not require an encrypted channel,
   click to clear the Require server verification (https:) for all
   sites in this zone check box.
4. In the *Add this Web site* to the zone box, **type the URL of a site**
   that you trust, and then click **Add**.
5. Click **OK two times** to accept the changes and return to Internet
   Explorer.

*Hope it helps!*